# HTTP Cloud Function returns 500 but there is no errors in the logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting a strange behaviour, I have a few http functions in Firebase Cloud Functions. They work perfectly, but there are days that they start returning status 500 for a while and then go back to working normal for a few minutes and then start returning status 500 again, this behaviour remains for the entire day.

The most strange part is that I don't get any error messages on my stack driver, in fact, there are no registries about these calls, it is as if the calls doesn't reach google's services somehow or it is just rejected and there are no registries about it.

I'll post the implementation of one of the most used functions in my application:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp()

exports.changeOrderStatus_1 = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) =>
{
    //Check Headers
    const clientID = request.get('ClientID');

    if(clientID === null || clientID === undefined || clientID === "")
    {
        console.error(new Error('clientID not provided.'));
        return response.status(500).send('clientID not provided.');
    }

    const unitID = request.get('UnitID');

    if(unitID === null || unitID === undefined || unitID === "")
    {
        console.error(new Error('unitID not provided.'));
        return response.status(500).send('unitID not provided.');
    }

    //Check body
    const orderID = request.body.OrderID;

    if(orderID === null || orderID === undefined || orderID === "")
    {
        console.error(new Error('orderID not provided.'));
        return response.status(500).send('orderID not provided.');
    }

    const orderStatus = request.body.OrderStatus;

    if(orderStatus === null || orderStatus === undefined || orderStatus === "")
    {
        console.error(new Error('orderStatus not provided.'));
        return response.status(500).send('orderStatus not provided.');
    }

    const orderStatusInt = Number.parseInt(String(orderStatus));

    const notificationTokenString = String(request.body.NotificationToken);

    const customerID = request.body.CustomerID;

    const promises: any[] = [];

    const p1 = admin.database().ref('Clients/' + clientID + '/UnitData/'+ unitID +'/FreshData/Orders/' + orderID + '/Status').set(orderStatusInt);

    promises.push(p1);

    if(notificationTokenString !== null && notificationTokenString.length !== 0 && notificationTokenString !== 'undefined' && !(customerID === null || customerID === undefined || customerID === ""))
    {
        const p2 = admin.database().ref('Customers/' + customerID + '/OrderHistory/' + orderID + '/Status').set(orderStatusInt);

        promises.push(p2);

        if(orderStatusInt > 0 && orderStatusInt < 4)
        {
            const p3 = admin.database().ref('Customers/' + customerID + '/ActiveOrders/' + orderID).set(orderStatusInt);

            promises.push(p3);
        }
        else
        {
            const p4 = admin.database().ref('Customers/' + customerID + '/ActiveOrders/' + orderID).set(null);

            promises.push(p4);
        }

        let title = String(request.body.NotificationTitle);
        let message = String(request.body.NotificationMessage);

        if(title === null || title.length === 0)
            title = "?????";

        if(message === null || message.length === 0)
            message = "?????";

        const payload = 
        {
            notification:
            {
                title: title,
                body: message,
                icon: 'notification_icon',
                sound : 'default'
            }
        };

        const p5 = admin.messaging().sendToDevice(notificationTokenString, payload);

        promises.push(p5);
    }

    return Promise.all(promises).then(r => { return response.status(200).send('success') })
        .catch(error => 
            {
                console.error(new Error(error));
                return response.status(500).send(error)
            });
})
```

And this is how I invoke it, the client application is running on Xamarin Forms app usinde the c# language:

```
        static HttpClient Client;

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            Client = new HttpClient();
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("My cloud functions adress");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("UnitID", UnitService.GetUnitID());
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ClientID", AuthenticationService.GetFirebaseAuth().User.LocalId);
        }

  public static async Task<bool> CallChangeOrderStatus(OrderHolder holder, int status)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CallChangeOrderStatus: " + status);

            try
            {
                var content = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                content.Add("OrderID", holder.Order.ID);
                content.Add("OrderStatus", status.ToString());
                
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(holder.Order.NotificationToken) && NotificationService.ShouldSend(status))
                {
                    content.Add("CustomerID", holder.Order.SenderID);
                    content.Add("NotificationToken", holder.Order.NotificationToken);
                    content.Add("NotificationTitle", NotificationService.GetTitle(status));
                    content.Add("NotificationMessage", NotificationService.GetMessage(status));
                }

                var result = await Client.PostAsync("changeOrderStatus_1", new FormUrlEncodedContent(content));

                return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException exc)
            {
#if DEBUG
                ErrorHandlerService.ShowErrorMessage(exc);
#endif
                Crashes.TrackError(exc);

                return false;
            }
        }
```

These functions are called several times a minute at a time but can go for up to an hour without being called.

I have sent the requests from mobile conections, wifi conections, wired conections and from various internet providers and the problem still happens nonetheless.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something? Is it instability in google servers?

Comment: using `blaze` plan ?

Comment: Yes, my functions work fine, I've been using them for weeks. It seems to be random, it just starts behaving like this out of the blue.

Comment: I have identified a pattern though, in both days the problem happened, google had had instability in theyr services(non related to cloud functions, but with cloud), but the odd behaviour remained long after the instability was solved. 

In both situation I redeployed ALL my functions and after a while it returned to normalty.

Comment: Your code is doing a lot of error checking (very smart) and is returning 500 with a unique error string. Which error string is being returned to the client. If it is not one of your errors, then it is an Internal Server error which points elsewhere such as function fails to start, crashes, GCP problem. If you are not seeing these messages in Stackdriver then it is probably one of the Internal Server types of errors. Monday there was a GCP outage but that is very rare.

Comment: All those error checks log something to the logs, so it isn't them. I get a 500 status response with just a "Internal server error" and when I go check the logs, there is nothing there. In both situations the issue with google services was solved within 2 hours, but the issues remained for the entire day and it seemed to go away only after I redeployed all my functions.

Comment: It has happened twice in two weeks, thats not very rare, I've sent an email to firebase support, I'm waiting to see if they have an insight on whats going on here. I've found this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117181234

Comment: I have the same problem in my application. External system sends events to my firebase cloud functions. From time to time I see failures (500 errors) in external system admin console, but don't see anything in firebase console. My assumption is that there might be a problem with scaling firebase functions if external app writes with high frequency.

Comment: I received an email from Firebase Support, they said these erronous behaviour is due to google servers instabilities and is now resolved.